# Connecting MQTT client to MQTT broker using SSL server certificate

Tags: ssl, mqtt, hivemq

I am trying to connect a MQTT client to hivemq mqtt broker using .pem file using the hivemq MQTT cli. I tried several commands according to the documentation but have not been able to connect yet and don't really know what could be the issue. Any help is appreciated

The documentation that I am looking at : https://hivemq.github.io/mqtt-cli/docs/shell/connect/

Commands that I tried :

```
con -h 'host' -u 'user' -pw 'password' --cafile /path/the-cert-name.pem
```

Comment: You are going to need to supply a LOT more context here. Which command like tool are you using? And what error's did you get?

Comment: I am using hivemq MQTT CLI. I am trying to connect to hivemq broker.I tried to use this command that I have mentioned in the post. When I execute this command I simply get connection timed out

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72354795/edit) the question when adding detail

Comment: A timeout implies that you have either got the hostname or port wrong, or there is a firewall dropping packets between you and the broker, but since you are using  MQTT over TLS and haven't specified a port that would be my first guess.

Comment: Oh that solved the issue. Thank you for the quick solution! @hardillb